# Slick DB drivers for different environments in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, slick

I have some data that I want to persist in the database. I identified that I would be using Postgres for my persistence needs. I however would like to use much lighter weight H2 database for testing. I have the following defined as my mapping:

```
import slick.lifted.Tag
//import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

class MyRepo(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String)](tag, "MyRepo") {

  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")

  def * = (id, name)
}
```

As it can be seen in the imports above, how can I map this once to use H2 database and once to use Postgres? I can configure different drivers and datasources in the application.conf of the Play framework and get the appropriate configurations for the different environments, but how can I use the MyRepo class above once for Postgres and once for H2?

Here is what I have in my application.conf:

```
myDbConf {
  url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  properties = {
    databaseName = "mydb"
    user = "myuser"
    password = "secret"
  }
  numThreads = 10
}
```

I'm doing:

```
Database.forConfig("myDbConf", config)
```

to get the reference to the underlying database!